# sap.ui.table not showing all rows

Tags: sapui5

I'm having an issue where the `sap.ui.table` is not showing all the rows, particularly the last few rows. My page layout is a `sap.ui.table.Table`

I want this to apply to many tables I use across many pages of the application.

[image: last VISIBLE row - not additional scrolling is possible]

last missing row

[image: last missing row]

I've researched this issue with SAP and Stack Overflow and found solutions ranging from `setVisibleRowCount`, `setRowHeight`, and etc. These do not work.

The one solution that inconsistently works is by manually setting `setFirstVisibleRow` when the user is at the bottom of the page and adding 1+.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any custom CSS style involved that somehow manipulates the height of the cells?

Comment: Please provide a sample code snippet with which we could reproduce the issue. Otherwise, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49119692/5846045.

Comment: What do you mean with "not shown"? Is the data fetched from the OData service but you need to scroll to see it? Or is the row only fetched after you scroll? Or is the value not fetched and not displayed at all?

Comment: With which UI5 version are you testing the app? Please share an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that other readers can reproduce the issue and help you with better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`sap.ui.table` defaults number of rows to 10. 
To display all the rows, one hack is during setting of the model to the table, set `setVisibleRowCount` with the length of records.

Note: `setVisibleRowCount` doesn't work from view sometimes for some reason. It works from controller though.

Comment: Thanks Vinay, I'd like to not use "setVisibleRowCount" and set "visibleRowCountMode" as "auto".

Comment: @biscotini917 Are you somehow wrapping the table with a `<VBox>`? In that case, the table needs to be able to grow / shrink. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921224/5846045. Let us know if that answer helps. Otherwise, please add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question.